# Pivot point for positioning Path in C# WPF canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

so i have this Path and i need to place it rotated by its center in a coordinate. so i have this static Path in .xaml

```
<Path Stroke="Black" RenderTransformOrigin="0.379,0.494" Canvas.Left="30" Canvas.Top="0">
    <Path.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <RotateTransform Angle="-38.28"/>
            <TranslateTransform X="-30" Y="-30"/>
        </TransformGroup>
    </Path.RenderTransform>
    <Path.Data>
        <PathGeometry>
            <PathGeometry.Figures>
                <PathFigureCollection>
                    <PathFigure StartPoint="75,30">
                        <PathFigure.Segments>
                            <PathSegmentCollection>
                                <LineSegment Point="0,0"/>
                                <LineSegment Point="12,30"/>
                                <LineSegment Point="0, 60"/>
                                <LineSegment Point="75, 30"/>
                            </PathSegmentCollection>
                        </PathFigure.Segments>
                    </PathFigure>
                </PathFigureCollection>
            </PathGeometry.Figures>
        </PathGeometry>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

but then i create it from code the same way and it just doesn't wanna center, it just starts rotating around the point

```
{
    PathGeometry pathGeom = new PathGeometry();
    Sprite = new Path
    {
        Data = pathGeom,
        RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.379, 0.5),
        Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(120, 0, 0, 0)),
        Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(120, 30, 200, 7))
    };

    var pf = new PathFigure { StartPoint = new Point(75, 30) };
    pf.Segments.Add(new LineSegment { Point = new Point(0, 0) });
    pf.Segments.Add(new LineSegment { Point = new Point(12, 30) });
    pf.Segments.Add(new LineSegment { Point = new Point(0, 60) });
    pf.Segments.Add(new LineSegment { Point = new Point(75, 30) });
    pathGeom.Figures.Add(pf);

    UpdateRotation();
    canvas.Children.Add(Sprite);
}

private void UpdateRotation()
{
    Sprite.RenderTransform = new TransformGroup
    {
        Children = new TransformCollection {
            new RotateTransform(Road.Angle + (Direction == -1 ? 90 : 0), -30, -30) , <-- i tried doing this
            new TranslateTransform(-30, -30), <-- and this separately, but they both didn't work
        }
    };
    Canvas.SetLeft(Sprite, Loc.X);
    Canvas.SetTop(Sprite, Loc.Y);
}
```

here's what the static path looks like:[what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhJKc.png)

Comment: Hi, It's not clear to me what you want. Do you want the path in c# code to be the same as the path in xaml?

Comment: i want the pivot point of the sprite to be set to the specific coordinate, and instead it places like the edge at this position

Answer (score 0):

You may simplify your drawing by defining the pivot point as origin - with coordinates `(0,0)`. There is no need for a TranslateTransform or a centered RotateTransform. You would also not have to create new transforms on each direction update. Just set the `Angle` property of the existing RotateTransform.

```
private Path Sprite { get; }

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Sprite = new Path
    {
        Data = Geometry.Parse("M0,0 L-12,-30 63,0 -12,30Z"),
        // or Data = Geometry.Parse("M-13,0 L-25,-30 50,0 -25,30Z"),
        // or whatever corresponds to the original RenderTransformOrigin

        RenderTransform = new RotateTransform(),
        Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(120, 0, 0, 0)),
        Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(120, 30, 200, 7))
    };

    canvas.Children.Add(Sprite);

    UpdatePosition(100, 100, 45); // for example
}

private void UpdatePosition(double x, double y, double direction)
{
    ((RotateTransform)Sprite.RenderTransform).Angle = direction;
    Canvas.SetLeft(Sprite, x);
    Canvas.SetTop(Sprite, y);
}
```

Comment: yea, but i need the path to rotate and then get positioned by its pivot, and it doesn't wanna do that, it just moves away

Comment: The positioning is done by setting Canvas.Left and Top. Have you not tried it out?

Comment: the problem is that the rotation completely messes up the pivot point, so the sprite is completely off the position and barely even touches it
... like, i set it to 60;60 and after rotation it decides to place the center point to like 83;74

Comment: Have you drawn the shape as shown here, with coordinate origin at the pivot point?